# Gift Aid - help needed

Tags: civireport

I am very behind with GA claims, partly because I find it so difficult to remember how to generate the report I need out of Civi. I don't get on with extensions - I don't have the technical ability - so just want an aide memoire for how to run the report for each quarter in order to populate the HMRC template (I am comfortable with that end of it). I don't use Civi day-to-day, only for this report really. Can anyone help with a reminder of how to do it? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the UK Gift Aid extension the official documentation has some really useful guidance for all of it, including how to generate the relevant report/batches

https://docs.civicrm.org/ukgiftaid/en/latest/batches/

Do have a look and if you have any more questions or need further guidance just update your question and I'm sure a member of the community will be able to help.

Comment: Thank  you but I did say I don't want to use the extension, it's beyond my abilities :) 
I just want to know how to filter the data for the report to HMRC.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just read it as that you're not that familiar with it rather than not having the extension. And I'm afraid, I can't help in that case as I'm don't know of a report that can be run without the extension that would only show contributions that are eligible for GiftAid etc.

Comment: Do you have the GA extension installed? This affects the answer, as the report will be different.

Answer (score 0):

Gift Aid is complicated but the Gift Aid extension is intended to simplify handling it in Civi.  You are going to need to do a lot of extra work in Civi to handle GA if you don't want to use the extension.

Some extensions do require more technical knowledge to install and configure but those that are available to install from the `Add New` tab of the `Administer > System Settings > Extensions` should be well tested and easy to install (sometimes referred to as 'in-app distribution').

If you don't feel confident doing that it is probably worth talking to someone (see [list](https://civicrm.org/civicrm/experts)) to help get Civi configured appropriately for your needs, including Gift Aid.